# Can't generate PDF report with JasperReports

Tags: java, jasper-reports

this error is blowing my mind away, so any help is appreciated. So the thing is, I'm dealing with a web application using JSF where there's a need to generate a report so that the user can download it. BUT, whenever I try to generate the report, I get this stack trace:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRStyledTextParser
    net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.<init>(JRBaseFiller.java:110)
    net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.<init>(JRVerticalFiller.java:69)
    net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.<init>(JRVerticalFiller.java:57)
    net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.createBandReportFiller(JRFiller.java:200)
    net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.createReportFiller(JRFiller.java:215)
    net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:84)
    net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:456)
    net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:863)
    br.com.ead.jasper.RelatorioUtil.geraRelatorio(RelatorioUtil.java:43)
    br.com.ead.web.RelatorioBean.gerarRelatorio(RelatorioBean.java:31)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:158)
    javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:79)
    org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:159)
    org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:184)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
    org.primefaces.component.filedownload.FileDownloadActionListener.processAction(FileDownloadActionListener.java:53)
    javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:813)
    javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)
    javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
    br.com.ead.filter.CharsetFilter.doFilter(CharsetFilter.java:26)
    br.com.ead.filter.ConexaoHibernateFilter.doFilter(ConexaoHibernateFilter.java:42)
    br.com.ead.filter.LoginFilterProfessor.doFilter(LoginFilterProfessor.java:35)
```

The error seems to be pretty straightfoward. Looks like this class `class net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRStyledTextParser` is missing, but it actually is in my classpath. I just can't find a way to make this work! I'm using maven as a dependecy manager, so here are my dependencies:

```
<dependencies>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/joda-time/joda-time -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.8</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.primefaces/primefaces -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>5.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.11.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.23</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.jasperreports/jasperreports -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.itextpdf/itext-pdfa -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>itext-pdfa</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.11</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.primefaces.extensions/all-themes -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId>
            <artifactId>all-themes</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.8</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet.jsp.jstl/javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-logging/commons-logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.3</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-collections/commons-collections -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-digester/commons-digester -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-digester</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-digester</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.itextpdf/itextpdf -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.11</version>
        </dependency>




        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-servlet-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>9.0.0.M26</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.01</version>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Once again, any help is appreciated.

Comment: NoClassDefFoundError is usually about not being able to load class because of a missing dependency of the class (for example, an import that cannot be resolved), not about class itself not being present. I mean, it's probably not that JRStylesTextParser is not present in the classpath, and instead that another class it relies on is missing. i would put debug breakpoint on that class being thrown to follow the thread, or look at that class source code to check if all its class dependencies are also present in classpath.

Comment: Hey, thanks for taking the time to answer. I looked into the source code of JRStyleTextParser, and all of the imports can be resolved. I even copied and pasted them in my code to make sure. Any other ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: Did you try to debug? Did you try to run the same code from simple application (simple class with static main, for example)?

Comment: Is this the entire stack trace? This somewhat confusing NoClassDefFoundError is typically thrown when something goes wrong in a static block.

Comment: @JeffersonTavares You should post the small *jrxml* to reproduce a problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So based on your pom, you are using version 5.0.0 of Jasper Reports. Based on [this version](https://github.com/Jaspersoft/jasperreports/blob/jr-5-0-0/jasperreports/src/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/util/JRStyledTextParser.java#L80) of the class in question, the static block that is causing this error doesn't log or print any errors that may have been thrown during static initialization.

You have two options:

1. Look at the source I linked and see if you can determine what might be throwing an exception in that static initialization block, fix it, then proceed
2. Upgrade your jasper reports version to *at least* 6.3.0. As of [this version](https://github.com/Jaspersoft/jasperreports/blob/jr-6-3-0/jasperreports/src/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/util/JRStyledTextParser.java#L79) of the class in question, they have at least started printing the stack trace of the underlying issue. This ought to give you a better idea of what the actual error is.

Comment: upgrading every single dependency and adding some new ones not listed in the Jasper Reports official documentation fixed it for me :)